# Does Jenkins support cloning git submodules with "git@" (not "https") URLs?

Tags: jenkins, git, jenkins-plugins

Had some issues with Jenkins when trying to checkout a project with Git nested submodules. It failed with a permission error when cloning the submodules:

```
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive some/path" returned status code 128:
stdout: Submodule path 'some/path': checked out '34e663c11661b5153076c1d624ead25137df0783'

stderr: Cloning into 'some/other/path'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:foo/foo.git' into submodule path 'some/other/path' failed
Failed to recurse into submodule path 'some/path'
```

In the Jenkins job, checking out submodules is enabled:
In the Git plugin under `Advanced sub-modules behaviours`, the options `Recursively update submodules` and `Use credentials from default remote of parent repository` are enabled.
All git repositories are private Github repositories, but the Jenkins user has read access to them.

The only way to get it working as by replacing `git@...` URLs by `https://...`. For instance, this here would fail

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = some/path
    url = git@github.com:foo/foo.git
```

... but this would work

```
[submodule "foo"]
    path = some/path
    url = https://github.com/foo/foo.git
```

I cannot rule out that there is a misconfiguration on our end. But still I have some generic understanding question:

- Does the Jenkins Git plugin support `git@` URLs? Or is it a known limitation that you need to use `https://...` URLs?
- Why does the choice of the protocol make a difference on Jenkins? Is it because `git@` assumes that SSH keys of Jenkins were added to the Github repository?

Comment: Host key verification failed

Comment: @030 My guess is that "git@" fails because the SSH key is not properly installed. That would mean it is a configuration error and not a limitation of Jenkins.

Comment: What happens if you do a git clone on the Jenkins server?

Comment: @030 Have not access to the machine myself. But I'll try to look into that direction. Looks like that is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a reference, it works for our system, submodules over SSH. We use deploy keys for this purpose. In Gitlab they can be found under *Settings* --> *Repository* --> *Deploy Keys*. The used key has to be marked as *Enable* in each used Git repository (main and submodules).

Answer (score 1):

Are the credentials you are using a username/pass or token? If so, that will work for http cloning, but will fail for git@ since that uses ssh keys to authenticate.

There is another option you can select called "Checkout over SSH" that comes from the [Github Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin). You will need to add a new "SSH Username with Private Key" credential to Jenkins where you can select to either upload a private key, use a file, or use the one on jenkins master (usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa`). The corresponding public key will need to be added to your Github profile or repo settings.